# Using React.Memo on a component which is being rendered in two different places

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component which returns the same result at all times.

I need to render the component at two different places conditionally.

one is in navigator for certain routes, and the other place is in one of the child components for other routes.

When I use React.memo on the component; its memoizing the component when navigator render is unmounting and child is rendering. But its not memoizing when child component is unmounting and parent is rendering.

Any leads on how to fix this?

The component Im taking about is Banner which should always be at the top of the screen.

```
<ExampleBanner />
```

So the Banner should be rendered from two places conditionally without flickering.

```
<Navigator>
{route.name !== 'Home' ? <ExampleBanner /> : null}
<AnotherComponent />
<Navigator/>


const AnotherComponent = () => {
return {route.name==='Home' ? <ExampleBanner /> : null}
```

So when go from Homescreen to any other route; or coming from any other route to home screen; the banner is re rendering and causing a flicker.

So, to avoid this flickering, I am using React.memo to avoid the component from rerendering. But not sure why this is not working as expected.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your code, your case is a bit hard to understand with words

Comment: @bgeffrault - I added the code in the description